# Friendship theorem for bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, conjectures, bipartite-graphs

The friendship theorem states that if every pair of people has exactly one  common friend, then one person is friends with everybody. Which is unfortunately not easy to actually proof. I came up with the following variation on this theorem regarding  bipartite graphs:

if every pair of females  has exactly one mutual male friend, and every pair of males has exactly one mutual female friend (the bipartite friendship condition), but the amount of females and males are  not equal, then one male is friends with every girl and one girl is friends with every boy.

If the amount of females and males are  equal and more than 3, then there is another possible configuration: there is a popular male and popular female, who are friends with everyone from the other gender , except with each other. Everyone else has  exactly 2 friends of opposite gender. [image: Example of bipartite friendship graph]

Can we prove that these are the only bipartite graphs satisfying the bipartite friendship condition?

Comment: The condition 'everyone has exactly one common friend' makes me think of cover free families. By the way, how did you constructed this particuler graph?

Comment: I keep searching for pairs that don't satisfy the friendship condition, and then I delete or add an edge  to based on their lack or surplus of  mutual neighbors. Eventually I end up with a feasible solution, significantly faster than brute force searching. If you place the popular vertices at the sides you get a more esthetic and regular drawing btw

Answer (score 3):

Think of the two sides of the graph instead as being "points" and "lines", with edges of the graph representing the incidence relation (lines passing through points). Then the friendship condition becomes:

1. Through any two points, there is a unique line.
2. Any two lines have a unique intersection point.

Of course, these are not necessarily geometric lines, but just a metaphor. (Incidence geometry studies the abstract objects represented by points and lines without a geometric meaning.)

The [De Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(incidence_geometry)) narrows things down. It tells us three things:

- Suppose that every line contains at least two points, and that not all points lie on the same line. (Both assumptions are necessary to rule out the "boring" construction.) Then there are at least as many lines as points.
- Taking the dual, suppose that every point lies on at least two lines, and that not all lines pass through the same point. Then there are at least as many points as lines.

We want both sets of assumptions, so we want both conclusions, and so there must be an equal number of points and lines. De Bruijn and Erdős described the equality case. There are two possibilities: first, we can see a "near pencil", which is a line with $n-1$ out of $n$ points on it, and an $n^{\text{th}}$ point with $n-1$ lines joining it to the other $n-1$ points. This is a geometric description of the second construction in the question.

The other equality case comes from finite [projective planes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane). Here, there must be $n = q^2+q+1$ points and $n = q^2+q+1$ lines, for some integer $q$ called the "order" of the projective plane. Each point lines on $q+1$ lines, each line passes through $q+1$ points, and (as desired) any two points lie on a unique line, and any two lines have a unique intersection.

Projective planes are known to exist when $q$ is a prime power, though we haven't ruled out the possibility that they exist in other cases. The simplest new construction this gives us is the [Fano plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fano_plane) for $q=2$:

[image: fano plane diagram from Wikipedia]

This can be turned into a bipartite graph with $7$ vertices on each side, where each vertex has $3$ neighbors on the other side, satisfying the condition in the problem.

[image: fano plane graph]

Though there are infinitely many projective planes that answer the question, I must also point out that they are all symmetric: the number of points equals the number of lines. This gives a balanced bipartite graph where both sides have an equal number of vertices.

By the converse of our application of De Bruijn–Erdős, if we have an unbalanced bipartite graph, the only possible construction is the "boring" one: one vertex from each side is adjacent to every vertex on the other side, and all other vertices have degree $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Misha!'ll need some time to fully grasp the theory. The 3-regular example you gave is interesting, I wondered whether regular graphs could be solutions but failed to generate one myself. So you could make a similar 4-regular graph on 13 x 2 vertices. I get that for a  k regular graph with the condition, every 3 walk ends up at a non-adjacent vertex. So $(k*(k-1)^2 $ possible walks end up in $n-k$ vertices, which leads to the same formula for n as you gave. But I don't immediately see why q must be prime power, I'll think about that some more I guess

Comment: You should not expect to see why $q$ must be a prime power, because that's an open problem :) The thing is that when $q$ is a prime power, we have a construction for the graph using finite fields: the [vector space construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Vector_space_construction) with coordinates in $\mathbb F_q$. When $q$ is not a prime power, we don't actually know how to construct this graph, but we don't have a proof that it doesn't exist.

Comment: Btw, we can also proof quite easily that any pair of non adjacent points from opposite partition must have the same degree. There must also exist a pair of vertices of the same partition that have equal degree, by a pigeonhole argument. But then, except for their mutual friend, every vertex of the other partition must have that same degree. So only one vertex per partition can differ